# Google sheets script request

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking to create a script that when a button is clicked, a popup window opens asking for a numeric value to be subtracted from a specific cell.

I have searched but have not been able to find an answer. Is this even possible?

Comment: Here is an [example](https://www.lido.app/tutorials/google-sheets-button-run-script) of creating a button to run a script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Run this first:

```
function launchModifyDialog() {
  let html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h3>Works on Active Cell</h3><input type="text" id="txt1" placeholder="Enter a number" /><input type="button" value="+" onClick="plus();" /><input type="button" value="-" onClick="minus();" /><script>function plus(){let v = document.getElementById("txt1").value;google.script.run.plus(v)};function minus(){let v = document.getElementById("txt1").value;google.script.run.minus(v)};</script></body></html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));
}

function plus(v) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sh.getActiveCell();
  const c = cell.getValue();
  if(!isNaN(v) && !isNaN(c)) {
    cell.setValue(Number(cell.getValue()) + Number(v));
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Invalid Values")
  }
}

function minus(v) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const cell = sh.getActiveCell();
  const c = cell.getValue();
  if(!isNaN(v) && !isNaN(c)) {
    cell.setValue(Number(cell.getValue()) - Number(v));
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Invalid Values")
  }
}
```